# Rounded corner around an image inside dive

Tags: html, css

I have to fetch an image from database and what I want `if we upload image without rounded corner and when image is  shown in screen it  is  in  rounded corner` .  For example:

```
<div class="images">

<a href="#" title=""> <img src="" ....></a>

</div>
```

So this image should be in rounded corner. I have done  some css like this:

```
  webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
 -ms-border-radius: 3px;
 -o-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;
```

but this does not work for me.  Please, can anyone help me with it?

Comment: And what selector are you using to apply that CSS?

Comment: Try this `code` .images > a { display: block; webkit-border-radius: 3px... etc } `code`

Comment: @DavidThomas images > a{}

Comment: Then you need to preface `images` with a period, to use a class-name: `.images > a` without there period, the CSS is trying to find an `images` element, not class.

Comment: See example http://jsfiddle.net/2vCZd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/34LCL/1/

```
HTML:
<div class="images">
<a href="#" title="foo"><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" alt="miaow" /></a>
</div>

CSS:
.images img {
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -ms-border-radius: 12px;
    -o-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.images > a > img{... border-radius:3px;}

if you do the rounding on the external elements you won't get the desired effect. You need to apply it on the actual img element.

or you could go

```
.roundedCornerImg{... border-radius:3px;}
```

and add that class to your image

```
<img class="roudedCornerImg"...>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you want,http://jsfiddle.net/QKRHq/2/:

```
.s {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: solid 4px #7fd;
    border-radius: 20%;
}
img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 20%;
}


<div class='s'>
    <img src='https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/bee436794e066a5423040cf673c7506f?s=140' />
</div>
```